# Why doesn't http://localhost/ load anything with WAMP?

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I recently tried installing WAMP but found that none of the pages will load. It also has an orange W logo, if that means anything. It does say (Tray Icon) that the *WAMPserver is online* though. I also did some research and found that Skype may cause problems and I removed the **Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections** option, but it still won't work. I get the following screen in my Chrome browser, any ideas?

[image: localhost isn't loading...]

**EDIT:** After further research I found that something may have gone wrong with the installation and Skype. I don't know how this happened but after a re-instillation everything worked fine. Thanks for your guy's help.

Comment: have you tried entering explicitly http://localhost ?

Comment: I think @Tomasz meant `http://localhost/`

Comment: Yes, Chrome automatically changes it but I have tried `http://localhost/`

Comment: I have also tried `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Try using `netstat -ano` and look addresses that have a listening state.

Comment: What am I looking for @Kevin Hikaru Evans

Comment: can you ping localhost ?

Comment: Look for a line that says it's using port 80, then check what PID is using that socket.

Comment: I guess what am I looking for, it spit out a lot like `4 packets` sent and received

Comment: What port number has WAMP been assigned to use?

Comment: 80 I guess, but then it says stuff like port is available and idk

Comment: Yes, Skype uses either port 80 or 443 for incoming connections. You can change the port settings on Skype to free your port 80 in Settings > Advance > Connection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The orange logo indicates that at least one service failed to start. You might try the following to troubleshoot the underlying reason:

1. Check that the Apache service is running. Left-click the WAMP tray icon and check that under `Apache > Service`, the option to start the service is disabled/grayed out. If not, your Apache service isn't running and that's the cause.
2. Check the port Apache is listening on. Again. left-click the WAMP icon, `Apache > httpd.conf` should open the configuration. Look for the `Listen XX` directive and note what the value for `XX` is. If not `80`, you should use the url `http://localhost:XX` instead.
3. If the value for `Listen` was indeed `80`, you might want to check what process is bound to port `80`. Left-click the tray icon, `Apache > Service > Test port 80`. This should tell you what process is bound to port `80`. If nothing is listening at port `80`, you should see the message `Your port 80 is not actually used.`. If Apache actually is listening on that port, you should see something like `Apache/<version> (Win32) PHP/<version>`.
4. Finally, check the Apache error log. Left-click the icon, `Apache > Apache error log`. Scroll to the end of the file and look for any messages that might be relevant.
5. Try a different browser
6. Telnet to port `XX` and see if you're able to connect.

Comment: When I test port 80 its says "Your port 80 is not actually used" and when I click on the ENABLED "Start/Resume Service" nothing happens... Also there is an option to "Install Service" but this does nothing aswell. Any ideas?

Comment: I also tried with a different browser with the same results :(

Comment: 1. Did you check the Apache error log? 2. When you clicked `Install Service`, a console windows should've opened - what did it say?

Comment: Also, have you modified the configuration file in any way? Did this setup ever work? Is Apache configured to listen on port 80?

Comment: it said ok installing but nothing happened

Comment: And you tried running it after that, right? Anything in the logs then?

Comment: nothing seems to change as I retry... this shouldn't be this hard lol

Comment: AFAICT, you're having trouble with running the service and this might have to do with your permissions - I'm not sure. You might try running the server from the command line manually - open a command prompt window and browse to where the Apache exe is - it should be under `<WAMP Install Directory>\bin\apache\Apache<ver>\bin` and run `httpd.exe -e debug`. This should start Apache and print debug level and higher messages. Any problems should show up here.

Answer (score 5):

For this problem go :

```
wamp > Apache > Service > Install Service
```

After Install Your Apache Is Ok `:D`

```
   if not running, open this address use your web browser:
   127.0.0.1
```

(usually This problem **see in Windows 8**)

Answer (score 2):

Skype uses port 80 if it is free. No need to uninstall skype, just start your webserver before skype and everything should be fine. Skype will find another port.