# WAMP Server doesn't load localhost

Tags: localhost, wamp

I have a "small" problem with my WAMP Server. Everything worked fine (WAMP is on port 8081 - free port no matter what program I have open) yesterday but today, I can't reach localhost:8081. It's just keep loading and loading and loading...

I have tried everything - open the port in my router and in my firewall, check that the port is currently open and reachable (which it is) and so on. I installed the latest Windows updates to Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit earlier this day, restarted my computer and boom - I can't reach localhost:8081. It worked perfectly before I restarted the computer.

The updates was KB2620704, KB2588516, KB2617657, and KB890830.

Please, help me! I'm literally dying inside if I can't work with my website. I have tried XAMPP too. Apach didn't wanted to be loaded (as usual) so I uninstalled it. I have even reinstalled WAMP Server 2 times since this happened. Even run CCleaner after each uninstall so everything with WAMP was gone before I installed it again.

Comment: I have even tried to change the port from 8081 to 80, 8080, or another port, but it doesn't work anyway. My hosts file in Windows contains only "127.0.0.1 localhost" without ". No comments or anything though, because I didn't have this file in Windows/System32/drivers/etc or anywhere else, so I created it.

Comment: what'S the error log say? have you tried to get a network tool or something to check what kind of request you get?

Comment: @BookOfZeus One of (or the only) creator(s) of WAMP Server connected to my computer via TeamViewer few weeks ago and tested everything he knew can cause some problems to WAMP. Nothing worked, so I reinstalled my operating system and now everything works again.

Comment: I got the solution :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246938/why-doesnt-http-localhost-load-anything-with-wamp/16946208#16946208

Answer (score 40):

Solution(s) for this, found in the official wampserver.com forums:

### SOLUTION #1:

This problem is caused by Windows (7) in combination with any software that also uses port 80 (like Skype or IIS (which is installed on most developer machines)). A video solution can be found  [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dLmPzzP6n4w) (34.500+ views, damn, this seems to be a big thing ! EDIT: The video now has ~60.000 views ;) )

To make it short: open command line tool, type "netstat -aon" and look for any lines that end of `":80"`. Note that`PID` on the right side. This is the process id of the software which currently uses`port 80`. Press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> to get into the Taskmanager. Switch to the tab where you can see all services currently running, ordered by PID. Search for that `PID` you just notices and stop that thing (right click). To prevent this in future, you should config the software's port settings (skype can do that).

### SOLUTION #2:

left click the wamp icon in the taskbar, go to apache > httpd.conf and edit this file: change `"listen to port ....  80"` to `8080`. Restart. Done !

### SOLUTION #3:

Port 80 blocked by "Microsoft Web Deployment Service", simply deinstall this, more info  [here](http://www.devlog.nl/apache-on-port-80-blocked-by-microsoft-httpapi2-0/)

By the way, it's not Microsoft's fault, it's a stupid usage of ports by most WAMP stacks.

IMPORTANT: you have to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` now with port `8080`, this means `127.0.0.1:8080` or `localhost:8080`.

Comment: i have to add something: you can also simply deinstall the IIS software ("internet information service") and skype via: Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> "IIS" or "Internet Information Service"

Comment: I had the same problem described above and i tried the SOLUTION #2 proposed by Panique and jv42 and then i tried localhost:8080 
It worked well.
Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Avast Antivirus was causing my problem, thanx!

Comment: "Microsoft Web Deployment Service" Helped me. Tnx

Answer (score 10):

I faced a similar problem. I tried everything with ports, hosts and config files.But nothing helped.

I checked apache error logs. They showed the following error

```
(OS 10038)An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket.  : AH00332: winnt_accept: getsockname error on listening socket, is IPv6 available?
```

Finally this is what solved my problem.

1) Goto command prompt and run it in administrative mode. In windows 7 you can do it by typing `cmd` in run and then pressing ctrl+shift+enter

2) run the following command:
    `netsh winsock reset`

3) Restart the system

Answer (score 4):

Change the port 80 to port 8080 and restart all services and access like localhost:8080/

It will work fine.

Comment: Explain why in your answer.