# wamp server localhost:8080 page shows errors

Tags: wamp64

This was the problem:
I had the problem that wamp server's localhost page displayed blank and  [I found the following stackoverflow link (Tharick's answer did the trick for me)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083979/wamp-server-doesnt-load-localhost). When I opened the localhost page as: localhost:8080 then the localhost page opened with errors as you can see in the attached image (I added some arrows for illustration purposee). As suggested in the localhost page I opened the file:

c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.51/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and found this:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerAdmin abc@gmail.com
  DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www"
  ServerName  localhost
  <Directory "/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin abc@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www"
    ServerName  "localhost"
  <Directory "/">
    order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 192.168.0
    Allow from ::1
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

192.168.0 is the login address for my router.
abc@gmail.com is a placeholder for my email address

I believe this error means that I have to enter localhost:8080 rather than localhost, only in order to see the wamp server page and I hope somebody has the answer, what the error message means.

[This shows the localhost page after entering localhost:8080 in my browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS1hO.png)

Additional: [This is a screen shot from the wamp server menu, which illustrates the error!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBYDz.png)

Comment: could you please run `httpd.exe -t` command inside the bin directory? It will shows syntax related information.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Program output was: Syntax OK

Comment: have you observed any errors in the error log?

Comment: Well quite frankly you have destroyed the `httpd-vhosts.conf` file. Lets go back to the beginning. 1. WHY did you think changing Apache's listening port from 80 to 8080 was necessary

Comment: Using the WAMPManager icon in the system tray do `right click wampmanager->tools->Add a Listen port for Apache` enter your 8080 in the dialog that will be presented to you